# When I Scroll the tableView, how can I know which cell is touch the Green Area

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

[The Screen In My Prototype](https://photos.app.goo.gl/5LfFTA8zNVWsIsua2)

My question is based on`The image in the link` *.  Because my reputation is not enough, I can't post any image here*

We assume **that Green Area in the image** is **fixed**.
And, my requirement is that When `a cell` contains the GA,  `that cell's`audioPlayer will speak the word in the cell, like *AirPod*

**OR**, you can regard my requirement as `When a cell contains the GA,  the text of that cell's label changes to "Touch the Green"`

**My question** is that when I Scroll the tableView, how can I get  `which one(Cell)` is containing the GA?
But I can’t find a way to get that(**some position/index information about That Cell**)

*could anyone help me ? ObjectiveC solution is OK, Swift solution is better for me, Thank you so much*

Comment: Can u share screenshot ? what do u need exact screen ?

Comment: Bcos, u cant use UITableView as UIPickerView. So possible share screen.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31515151/uiscrollview-scroll-by-offset there's an image in this link. I ask the question based on this image, Does this image make the question clear?

Comment: I understood ur logic. UIPickerView will save ur time. But, if u need this logic on UITableView means, screen need.

Comment: [the image in my prototype](https://photos.app.goo.gl/5LfFTA8zNVWsIsua2) I think I have to use UITableView(there're a lot of data in the server). my requirement is that When a Cell contains the Green Area which is fixed in the screen, a audioPlayer makes a voice.

Comment: Ok I undestood. But, if u want to check audio for last cell means, some what difficult. Hope u understood, what I am comin to say ?

Comment: I've edited the question, My requirement is nothing to do with audio, It's about **the Cell** who contains the Green Area.

Comment: Can u share ur mail ID ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CRHke3_AITf2mpjz45mp8fQXv8mpozKw/view?usp=sharing 

U can check video. This is u need right ?

Comment: Do u have checked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // We check cells here to set the state of whether it contains the green or not before the scrolling
    checkCells()
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    // And we are continuously checking cells while scrolling
    checkCells()
}

func checkCells() {
    tableView.visibleCells.forEach { cell in
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
            let rect = tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
            // This is the rect in your VC's coordinate system (and not the table view's one)
            let convertedRect = self.view.convert(rect, from: tableView)

            if convertedRect.contains(greenArea.frame) {
                cell.textLabel?.text = "Touch the Green"
            } else {
                cell.textLabel?.text = "Does not touch the Green"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Ruslan. Your code is clear and easy to understand, and it is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2):

In this code, I am using `GreenArea` as in Center of `UIView`. Some modification from `Ruslan's` Answer.

```
@IBOutlet weak var greenAreaVw: UIView!
var contHeight : CGFloat = 0.0
var eachRowHeight : CGFloat = 45
var topSpaceTableView : CGFloat = 62
var GreenAreaOriginY : CGFloat = 0.0

// Give UITableView Edge Insets in ViewDidLoad

contHeight = ((self.view.frame.size.height / 2) - eachRowHeight / 2 - topSpaceTableView)
userTblVw.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: contHeight, left: 0, bottom: contHeight, right: 0)
userTblVw.contentOffset.y = -contHeight
GreenAreaOriginY = greenAreaVw.frame.origin.y

/*-------------------         -----------------------*/
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

     checkCells()  
}

func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {

     checkCells()  
}


func checkCells() {

    userTblVw.visibleCells.forEach { cell in
        if let indexPath = userTblVw.indexPathForCell(cell) {

            let rect = userTblVw.rectForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
            let convertedRect = self.userTblVw.convertRect(rect, toView: self.view)

            if convertedRect.origin.y >= GreenAreaOriginY && convertedRect.origin.y < (GreenAreaOriginY + eachRowHeight)   
            {
                let contFloat : CGFloat = (eachRowHeight * CGFloat(indexPath.row)) - contHeight
                userTblVw.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: contFloat), animated: true)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Find below Screenshots:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help ，McDonal, your solution is so good by making a tableView have an effect like pickerView, more powerful than my requirement.

Comment: Don’t have enough reputation. when I get enough, I will upvote your answer

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    [0, 1, 2].forEach {
        let rect = tableView.rectForRow(at: IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0))
        if rect.contain(GAView.frame) {
            // play sound here
        }
    }
}
```