# Force UICollectionView scroll by each point (counter +1)

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, scrollview

I need to get each point of collectionView offset to calculate different constraints, but when I scroll collectionView very fast it's offset changes from 1 or 0.5 step to 30-100. I saw two answers on stackOverflow and mentioned that it necessary to use `func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>)` but how we can force collectionView to count every step with this method? Method from [UIScrollView scroll by offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31515151/uiscrollview-scroll-by-offset/31515205) doesn't work.

Comment: You say: *"when I scroll collectionView very fast it's offset changes ..."* -- if you want help with your code, you need to **show** your code. Please review [ask].

Comment: @DonMag implement ```scrollViewDidScroll``` method in VC with collectionView and print scrollView.contentOffset.y. You will see that it changes not with +1 counter. First value can be 10, the second 90, the third 140. So I want to know how to make it changes like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 with counter == 1, not 10 or 50 when it scroll's fast.

Comment: UIKit calls `scrollViewDidScroll` each time it updates the position... if the user is scrolling quickly, the position can **NOT** be updated for every point. Are you trying to ***prevent*** the user from scrolling quickly? If not, what are you really trying to do?

Comment: @DonMag Why the position can NOT be updated for every point?

Comment: @DonMag I'm not trying to prevent the user from scrolling quickly. I want to get each point of offset.

Comment: When scrolling, UIKit does not re-draw point-by-point. If it did, it would take more than 5 second to scroll one screen-width. I understand you *want* to get every point... but, ***WHY*** do you want that? If your collectionView is the full width (375 pts), and the user takes 1/2 second to drag across the screen, what are you trying to do ***375 times*** during that 1/2 second?